# Is it possible to run MirrorMaker in Kafka without using Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Looking to come up with solution that would mirror or replicate one Kafka environment without needing Kafka Connect. Having a hard time coming up with any possible solutions or workarounds. Very new to Kafka, would appreciate any thoughts and/or guidance!

Comment: Hi @Sarah, if you could let us know whats the issue in using Kafka Connect we might be better able to solve the issue. Alternatively, you can use [uReplicator](https://github.com/uber/uReplicator) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

MirrorMaker2 is based on Kafka Connect. The original MirrorMaker is not, however it is not recommended to use this anymore as it's not very fault tolerant.

Most Kafka replication solutions are built on Kafka Connect (Confluent Replicator as another example)

Uber uReplicator mentioned in the comments is built on Apache Helix and requires a Zookeeper connection, which Kafka Connect does not, so ultimately depends on what access and infrastructure you have available

Since Kafka comes with the Connect API and MirrorMaker2 pre-installed, there should be little reason to find alternatives unless it absolutely doesn't work for your use case (which is...?)